# Java Google Drive SDK SocketTimeoutException on File.insert.execute

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I have been using the Google Drive SDK in both Java and Objective-c for months now and suddenly today (Jul 10, 2013) inserting new files using the java api (google-api-client-1.15.0-rc.jar & version 1.14) is failing to execute on FileInsert.execute(). Here is the static helper method I've been using (basically a copy from the DrEdit tutorials):

```
    public static File insertFile(Drive driveService, String title, String description,
            String parentId, String mimeType, java.io.File content) {
        System.out.println("<GDrive insertFile> start");
        File body = new File();
        body.setTitle(title);
        body.setDescription(description);
        body.setMimeType(mimeType);

        if (parentId != null && parentId.length() > 0) {
            body.setParents( Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(parentId)) );
        }
        Insert fileInsert = null;
        System.out.println("<GDrive insertFile> before content attache");
        if (content != null && content.length() > 0) {
            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(mimeType, content);
            try { fileInsert = driveService.files().insert(body, mediaContent); }
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        } else {
            try { fileInsert = driveService.files().insert(body); }
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }

        try {
            if (fileInsert != null) {
                System.out.println("<GDrive insertFile> before execute");
                File file = fileInsert.execute();
                System.out.println("<GDrive insertFile> file posted " + file.getId());
                return file;
            } else return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Obviously System.out was used to locate the issue, it hangs up on "before execute". I haven't been able to find any posts about Google server issues or changes in how the api is to be used. Here is the error message that is logged when the app fails any time after 20 - 180 seconds:

```
An error occured: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no known issues with the client and I'm not able to reproduce. Is there any other issues that may lead you to not to be able to open a connection to the Google backend?

Comment: It didn't work from about 1pm - 1am ET yesterday. I made no changes and then it began working again, strange. Could this have been related to an api quota being reached? In the api console for this project it was showing 0% (with very few calls) usage however (as of around midnight), so perhaps this was merely some fluke!?

Comment: If quota has been reached, it should respond with a quota error instead of a socket connection one, fyi.

Comment: @BurcuDogan I'm getting `SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` a LOT when trying to insert a file.... Seems odd. It's been happening pretty frequently for past few days. What does it mean if I get this Exception? Should I retry the request? Is it possible the request succeeded? It's frustrating...