# SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out on Insert to Google Drive - is it retryable?

Tags: java, exception, google-drive-api

Similar to [Java Google Drive SDK SocketTimeoutException on File.insert.execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583630/java-google-drive-sdk-sockettimeoutexception-on-file-insert-execute)

Uploading thousands of files, one after the other, seems every 1 out of 50 files throws

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:687)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1323)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:36)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithoutGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:545)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:562)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeUploadInitiation(MediaHttpUploader.java:519)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:384)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:418)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
...
```

on `files().insert().execute()`

I'm not sure what it "means" that I'm getting this Exception when inserting a file.

1. Does it mean the insert request was not fulfilled, or not necessarily?
2. Does it simply mean the client did not hear back from the Google servers after it sent the insert request?
3. Should I be doing `exponential back-off and retry` when I get this error?

Comment: I'm facing this error too. By now, do you know if it is correct to do exponential backoff and retry?

Comment: I'm not positive, but looking back I think I did *not* treat it as retry-able, and instead just did as you do in your answer - increasing time out settings. As far as I know (and you can see from some of my other Google Drive related Q's) this may just be one of those things about Drive API that is a bit mysterious. Best of luck!

Comment: I will increase timeouts and I just moved to Drive v3. I hope the issue stops, but you never know :). Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I have the same issue. One possible solution is to increase the read timeouts:
**[Timeouts and Errors](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/errors)**

```
private HttpRequestInitializer setHttpTimeout(final HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer) {
    return new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
            requestInitializer.initialize(httpRequest);
            httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(3 * 60000);  // 3 minutes connect timeout
            httpRequest.setReadTimeout(3 * 60000);  // 3 minutes read timeout
        }
    };
}
...
service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, setHttpTimeout(credential)).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing to do is to try to prevent the timeout. I don't think there is any way to be sure if the error occurred before or after the insert post was completed. It's quite common to get 501 responses when there are internal timeouts within the Drive infrastructure, but your case is different. The only way to be sure is to set a private property on the file object, and then search Drive to see if a file with that property exists (eg. mygeneratedId = some_random_UUID).

If you're inserting thousands of files simultaneously, it's conceivable that you are choking some resource (sockets, bandwidth, etc). You might want to try throttling your inputs slightly.

Comment: Is it possible that the file may have been only partially uploaded if I get this exception? In other words, maybe there *is* a file up there, with the ID, but there was an error as it was being uploaded and thus it does not have the entire file? I'm wondering that as I consider how to handle this exception in applications

Comment: Unlikely. Your question doesn't say if you're (1) using resumable upload or (2) whether you're converting to google format. If (1), you can presumable just resume, and if not (2) you can look at the md5Sum of the file.

Comment: (1) - I'm not using resumable upload. Do you know of relevant docs for doing that with client lib? Or is it just accessable with REST?, and (2) I'm not converting it to google format. I was thinking of comparing the size of the file in drive with the local file to see if it made it all the way. Is there any benefit of mdf5Sum rather than just size in bytes?

Comment: 1) dunno. I try to avoid the libraries. Perhaps post that as a discrete question on SO. 2) comparing on length alone always runs the slight risk that a truncated data set was padded out to the correct length. Given hash algorithms were invented for this specific purpose, it kinda makes sense to use the right tool for the job.

Comment: thanks pinoyyid (google drive developer/support team should have hired you already imo...). Out of curiosity, if you don't use the sdk/client libraries, what do you use / what documentation is there?

Comment: I just call the HTTP REST API directly from my code. I tend to architect my apps to do Drive access directly from an AngularJS/JavaScript client rather than from my Java server (usually AppEngine) as it gives me better scalability. To that end, I'm working on an AngularJS library ngGAPI to deal with the most common Drive issues that people encounter (401, 501, 403, etc).

Comment: The feeling I'm getting is that for almost every error that can occur when uploading to drive, it's ambiguous if the request succeeded or not. That means that for **every** error when uploading a file, I need to check if it succeeded or not, and whether to retry? Just seems like so much work. Even SocketTimeoutException leaves it ambiguous as to whether or not the file upload succeeded?